# Indesign CS6: Applying "show/hide" function to elements on separate pages from trigger

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, pdf, forms, interaction

Is it possible to apply a "show/hide" function to an element on one page that effects elements on other pages throughout a document?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, that's possible.

You may, however, add this functionality in Acrobat, as InDesign may not provide the needed user interface to do it.

Comment: HOW IS IT DONE??!!!!!.... in indesign that is. lol.  I had deemed it impossible because when I set a radio button to show/hide something, it only lists the elements on that same page with the radio button, it doesn't show anything else on any of the other pages in the questionnaire. How do you access those things?

Comment: how is it done in Acrobat?  I can't find any tutorials on it, or is it called "show/hide" in acrobat?

Comment: Have you tried the show/hide action?